# AdMob, Cannot access the payments or billing page

Tags: admob

**Xcode 7.3, iOS 9.3**

I understand that **this is not a programming question**, but someone who is implementing AdMob might be stumped by this.  Please drop a comment if you know where a post like this would go, if not here.

I just spent 3 days trying to figure this out...  I am posting a question and solution to my dilemma in hopes of saving someone who is new to AdMob some valuable time.

If you signed up for AdMob and integrated the SDK in your app., then you probably want to ensure that your payment and billing information is set up correctly too, before proceeding with app. submission.  Well, it was not so easy for me...

So you'd click the "gear" to get the settings popover to appear...

[image]

Then try to navigate to "Payments" and "Billing" to set up, well you guessed it, payments and billing...  However, I saw the following behavior:

The page you are directed to continuously loads...   As indicated by the google beach ball loading animation.

[image]

This goes on for about 3 minutes, and then you get...

[image]

Being new to AdMob and following the provided advice "...Please try again later" I tried again later, then later, then later - figuring it was due to traffic volume or whatever.  It was not, eventually I got frustrated enough and started looking for help.

Please see my answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Xcode 7.3, iOS 9.3**

After hours of stumbling around on the internet, I found this in the FAQ section of AdMob Help.

[Cannot access the payments or billing page](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3369446?hl=en)

The issue was that I had the incorrect cookie settings.  Yes.  Why they couldn't code a little more description to the error is beyond me, but I really feel that "...try again later" is a poor choice of words.

To add fuel to the fire, their solution is a bit outdated, the new Safari browser does not exactly have the correct cookie setting they describe.  But nonetheless, I understood what the problem is...

If you use Safari, then do this:

Go to the "Preferences" for Safari...

[image]

Navigate to the "Privacy" tab and change the "Cookies and website data:" from any other setting to "Always allow".

[image]

Reload the AdMob "Payment" or "Billing" page and you should see the corresponding content.

Hope this saves someone time!  Cheers.

*P.S.  You most likely will not be able to configure your payment method, because...*

> You can only select a payment method after the finalized earnings in
>   your transaction history have reached at least $10.00 or your local
>   currency equivalent.

Comment: in macOS Mojave, Privacy settings not has option to Always Allow...how to do it ?

Comment: @Guru You need to uncheck _Prevent cross-site tracking_ which you can find in the _Privacy_ tab then reload the page

Comment: @Elisabeth Thanks for this reply.

Comment: Unchecking "Prevent cross-site tracking" doesn't help. I'm still not able to see any content on payment page. I can access everything Google in Safari except this page. What is so special on this page that Safari doesn't load? I even emptied cache but it didn't help.

Comment: any new way to do with safari

Answer (score 15):

In Safari 14.0, go into *Preferences > Privacy,* **uncheck** `Prevent cross-site tracking`. Then, reload AdMob Payments page. [image]

Answer (score 6):

Try using a different browser, the same thing happened to me when using safari, but when I used google chrome the payments tab loaded fine.

Answer (score 4):

It's ridiculous, but you have to turn off blocking third-party cookies in Chrome. Make sure to turn that block back on when you're done, or preferable, not use Chrome.

[image]

The payment screen will look like this.
[image]

Comment: Cookies enabled.  Looks like Google has not properly setup CORS on their server... Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://play.google.com/log?format=json&hasfast=true. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://play.google.com’).

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://play.google.com/log?format=json&hasfast=true. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://play.google.com’).

Comment: i am not getting How to get paid section after trying to change my bank account , though i have already crossed the threshold, do you know the reason?

Comment: as of juin 2021 this solution seems to be working, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you disable **Ad-blocking extensions** in your browser for this site, otherwise Admob (and similar pages) won't work

Answer (score 2):

Enable Cookies in Your Browser Settings.

This changes work to Access payment page in Google Admob.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to login into your AdSense account and setup billing there. It fixed a similar issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same Issue with **Google Chrome Version 98.0.4758.102**

1. Allow Cookies  --> [Turn cookies on or off](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61416?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)

[image]

However this **Did not solve the issue completely**

In may case I add this Chrome Extension: **[Moesif Origin & CORS Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc)** turned on, by turning it off it solved the issue.

What I suggest is to check your extension in your browser (Adn, Firefox, Safary, Edge) and try again after you also enabled the Cookies.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but after allowing all cookies and removing all extentions page still didn't load. Finally logout and login to google account have solved the problem.